# Which iOS emojis are currently available across most (all?) modern platforms?

Tags: ios, keyboard, font, compatibility, emoji

I used the "rolling eyes" emoji available in my iOS keyboard in a social media post, but was dismayed to find that it isn't available on my Chrome on windows 7 computer. While I could install fonts/extensions/etc to "fix" the problem on my computer's end, I actually want all my social media audience (such as it is) to enjoy all of my posts.

Is there a list or resource that shows which iOS emoji's are available broadly on windows 7+ and osx with IE, Chrome, and Firefox, and on iOS 5+ and Android 4+?

If not, can we make one here in a single wiki style answer?

Comment: Windows 7 is likely the problem.  Microsoft at one point had a strategy to include many character sets only when language packs were purchased (or the pro version of Windows).  In Windows 10 I haven't noticed unavailable characters nearly as often, but have seen occasionally.

Comment: Can Windows 7 even do color emoji?   http://blog.getemoji.com/post/82224498347/how-to-use-emoji-in-windows-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see a full comparison of most current platforms at https://emojipedia.org
but only as far back as [Windows 8.0](https://emojipedia.org/microsoft/windows-8.0/)

For Windows 7: http://classic.getemoji.com

Comment: Does that page show what emoji will be available on Windows 7?

Comment: @TomGewecke have clarified and expanded answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be surprised to find anyone compiling such info for the nearly 2000 emoji for old os's.  In any case, display depends primarily on the local font installed, so if fonts can be added, more emoji can normally be displayed on any OS.  See this chart for some info:

http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html